# fb.ui feed dialog not working well on IOS

Tags: fb.ui

I used FB.ui to create a share dialog.
Here my coffeescript code:

```
FB.ui
  method: "feed"
  link: "facebook.com"
, (response) ->
  if response and response.post_id
    console.log("shared")
```

It works well on desktop browser and android but it doesn't work well on IOS (Safari & Chrome).

Problem is:

- when i didn't sign in my facebook account and then I click share, it will redirect to new tab and request to login, after that I can share.
- but when my facebook account sign in ready and then I click share, it doesn't show share dialog. it show only blank page.

Anyone ever meet this? How can I solve this???

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to the code:

```
display: 'touch'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
FB.ui(
                    {
                        method: 'share',
                        href: url,
                        mobile_iframe: true
                    },
                    function(response){
                        document.location.href = url;
                    });
```

But didn't work on iPhone so I decided to redirect the browser to the share url of Facebook like this:

```
document.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=APPID&display=popup&&link=https%3A%2F%2Fyourdomain.com%2Furl&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyourdomain.com.com%2Furl
```

Keep in mind that for : the code is %3A and / %2F. You will have to replace as such for it to pick them up.

Hope it helps